# data.table rolling/windowed geometric mean

Tags: r, statistics, data.table

**Question:**
Is there a clean and fast-running way to compute geometric mean using data.table?

**Background:**
So I am using this:

```
my_col_list <- names(mydata)[ my_start:ncol(mydata)]
my_name_list<- paste0(my_col_list, "_", "arithmean")
mydata[, (my_name_list) := unlist(lapply(.SD,
                                      function(x) rollapply(x,
                                                            5,
                                                            mean,
                                                            na.pad = TRUE)), 
                               recursive = F),
       .SDcols = my_col_list]
```

But I want to compute [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean).  I am working on ~20 million rows and ~1500 columns, so a fast-runing built-in is preferred.

I saw these ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602583/geometric-mean-is-there-a-built-in)) ways of computing geometric mean, but they are hand-coded so they are going to be slower.  This ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741280/geometric-mean-of-rows-in-a-data-table-in-r)) is about an overall geometric mean, not a windowed/rolling geometric mean.

Packages that have hand-coded (slower-running) geometric means include:

- [psych](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/index.html), [geometric.mean](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/1.7.5/topics/geometric.mean), hand coded
- [EnvStats](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/EnvStats/index.html), [geoMean](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/EnvStats/versions/2.1.0/topics/geoMean), hand coded with more error checking
- [compositions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/compositions/index.html), [geometricmean](https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/compositions/html/geometricmean.html), hand coded
- [caroline](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caroline/index.html), [geomean](https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/caroline/html/geomean.html), hand coded
- [PerformanceAnalytics](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/PerformanceAnalytics.pdf), mean.geometric, hand coded
- pracma, geomean, hand coded
- FinCal, geometric.mean, a novel hand-coded version (prod vs. mean)
- fdaMixed, dataTrans, hand-coded
- evolqg, MeanMatrix, hand coded, operates on covariance matrices, uses chol

not mean, but it is fast:

- Gmedian, Gmedian, median instead of mean, but built to be faster.  Uses Rcpp for compute.

maybe, but not sure:

- rotations, mean.SO3

Comment: `rollapply(x, 5, geometric.mean, na.pad = TRUE)` change to this

Comment: You should post a reproducible example of data along with necessary library() calls so that your code runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using your own code with package `psych` function `geometric.mean`

```
mydata[, (my_name_list) := unlist(lapply(.SD,
                                      function(x) rollapply(x,
                                                            5,
                                                            geometric.mean,
                                                            na.pad = TRUE)),recursive = F),
       .SDcols = my_col_list]
```

Comment: The psych version is hand-coded.  It is "exp(mean(log(x), na.rm=TRUE))".  If you type "edit(geometric.mean)" after "psych" is loaded then it shows you the code.  This is not actually a built-in/compiled version.

Comment: @EngrStudent If you do want something much quicker , I prefer `Rcpp` and writing you own function by`C++`

Comment: I haven't used Rcpp yet.  Can you give me a link to a "starter example" that can get me moving?

Comment: See this link different question , but Rccp performance better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045318/efficient-calculation-of-var-covar-matrix-in-r

Comment: Rollapply has deprecated na.pad.  Instead use "fill=NA".